# Trying to output an if else if, else loop. using arrays and Scanners. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Trying to output an if else if, else loop. using arrays and Scanners, to create a very basic encryption program for an assignment. Using the scanner i can input integers, however the loop won't execute. What am i doing wrong?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Question1A2 {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\t-------------------------");
    System.out.println ("\tIO's 4-digit Encrypter");
    System.out.println("\t-------------------------");


 System.out.print("Please enter the four digit number you would like to encyrpt: ");

int[] arr = {S.nextInt(),S.nextInt(),S.nextInt(),S.nextInt()}; 

 int a = arr[0] %10 +7; 
 int b = arr[1] %10 +7;
 int c = arr[2]%10 +7;
 int d = arr [3] %10 +7;

 int i = arr.length; 

 for(;;){
  if  (arr.length > 9999) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, but that is not a four digit number. Program will terminate.");
      System.out.println("Thank you for using Zito's 4-digit Encrypter program.");
break;
  }

else if (arr.length < 1000) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, but that is not a four digit number. Program will terminate.");
  System.out.println("Thank you for using Zito's 4-digit Encrypter program.");
   break;
   }

 else {
 System.out.print("The encyrpted version of your input is ");

 System.out.print(a);
 System.out.print(b);
 System.out.print(c);
 System.out.print(d);

break;
}

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why should the loop execute? You appear to be breaking out of it no matter what.

Comment: You have a break statement in every single case inside your loop. Do you know what a break statement does? If not, either remove it or look it up. The short answer is that NOT looping is exactly what this code is supposed to do. Also, why do you check if the length of `arr` is `> 9999`? The length of the array is always 4.

Comment: When is `arr.length` ever going to be anything other than 4? I'm assuming you're trying to check if the user entered a number with the wrong number of digits, but that isn't actually possible with your code, and that is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @jonhopkins, yeah exactly what i trying to do. i guess my question now is, How do i make sure the  user inputs 4 integers, no more or no less. and if they do, the if, else if statement runs. if they do input 4 integers, my else statement runs.

Comment: Do you want it to keep letting them try until they put in a valid number?

Comment: No, if they enter too many or too little integers. program quits.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure why you want it to be in a loop, but answer is coming up

Comment: okay awesome thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop for what you are trying to accomplish. Based on your code, it looks like what you are trying to do is get a number that should be between 1000 and 9999, and encrypt and output each digit if the number is valid or exit the program if it is not valid.

To start, you only need to get the single number, not get each digit individually. Then check if it is between 1000 and 9999. This check can be done in one if statement so that you don't have to repeat the code telling the user the number is bad. If the number is okay, then you can break it up into the four digits and encrypt each one.

```
int theNumber = S.nextInt();
if (theNumber < 1000 || theNumber > 9999) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, but that is not a four digit number. Program will terminate.");
    System.out.println("Thank you for using Zito's 4-digit Encrypter program.");
}
else {
    // I'm leaving this up to you to figure out how to get each digit.
    // There are several ways to do it, and it's out of scope for this question anyway.
    int digit1 = ...
    int digit2 = ...
    int digit3 = ...
    int digit4 = ...

    int a = digit1 % 10 + 7; 
    int b = digit2 % 10 + 7;
    int c = digit3 % 10 + 7;
    int d = digit4 % 10 + 7;

    System.out.print("The encrypted version of your input is ");

    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.print(b);
    System.out.print(c);
    System.out.print(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters a four digit number here:

```
int[] arr = {S.nextInt(),S.nextInt(),S.nextInt(),S.nextInt()};
```

the scanner will use the whole number as the input.  To resolve, you could ask for 4 digits separated by spaces and get the `S.nextInt()` four times or break the input int up like you did here:

```
int a = arr[0] % 10 + 7;  
int b = arr[1] % 10 + 7;
int c = arr[2] % 10 + 7;
int d = arr[3] % 10 + 7;
```

except assign the input to a variable first then use the following to get each number:

```
int i = S.nextInt();
int a = i / 1000;  
int b = (i / 100) % 10; 
int c = (i / 10) % 10; 
int d = i % 10;
```

and then assign it each number to the array as you did before.

Also, as mentioned above, your array length is 4.  One way to accomplish your goal could be to let the user input a four digit number, then use the if/if else to determine if the whole int is > 1000 || < 9999, then break the number down into single digits.

By the way, you have a typo with the word encrypt.